# identify that no Gridview Row is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a mark up gridview that let's the user select a row. 
There's a submit button. When you click on the submit button the information of the row is retrieved, but if you press submit and no row has been selected, there's a null error.

How can I identify that no gridview row has been selected? for some reason I don't have the option of gridview1.**selectedrows**.count>0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if(gridview1.SelectedIndex == -1){
    //no item has been selected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GridViewRow row = gridview1.SelectedRow;

if (row != null)
{}
```